# Codeigniter remove /index.php from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Okay so I know that a lot of people have been asking the same or similar questions, but I don't seem to find a solution that works for my project. So please don't put this as a duplicate.

I have a website made with codeigniter. It was running just fine without the index.php in the url. So the rewrite was successfull. Until a few days ago: all of a sudden the admin area (/admin) returned a 404 and was only accessible by the path '/index.php/admin'. The rewrite code that once used to work didn't do a thing anymore.

And know I'm back at the start -> **the problem is that I cannot delete the index.php from my url.**

I tried so many things that I don't know what to do anymore.

The application is stored under 'public_html/application/...
The image below is inside the application folder where the .htaccess file and index.php are.
Is this the right location to change the .htaccess?

[image]

I tried rewriting the .htaccess but without success:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^CI/(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots|css\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mysite.be/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "c_home/index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = "c_home/adminpanel";
$route['logout'] = "c_login/logout";
```

Does anybody have a clue what is going on or how this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your apache logs? And double check mod rewrite is enabled just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been messing around with this and finally made it work

For this I made changes to the htaccess and controllers.
I changed the admin function to a new controller and changed this in the routes.php

new routing

```
$route['admin'] = "c_login/index";
```

new .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess should be in the public_html directory -- ie: one level up from the current location.
The index.php is presumably in public_html already and 
The index.* you have in the picture is index.html -- as it should be. 
If .htaccess is in the right place per the above, then this .htaccess code will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Okay this made some progress but not yet there. I moved the .htaccess and now I'm redirected to the homepage whenever I type /admin behind my url.

Comment: try this route: $route['admin'] = "c_home/adminpanel/index";

Comment: more-specifically, you ended up at the default route because you are getting a 404 on admin. i'm guessing you are trying to get to the index function of the adminpanel controller class and if so then try this route: $route['admin'] = "c_home/adminpanel/index";

Comment: Hmm c_home is the controller and adminpanel is the function im trying to get. What would be the correct routing in this case?

Comment: And if I put $route['default_controller'] = "c_home/adminpanel"; then the routing works, the admin area is shown if I type just the url. But when I do $route['admin'] = "c_home/adminpanel"; it doesnt do anything if I add /admin to the url.

Comment: anymore thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try set

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'
```

And set

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: in combination with what .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

If we need a remove /index.php from url in codeigniter
Than

### application/config/config.php

```
  $config['index_page'] = '';

  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

### add .htaccess file at root directory of project

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /[Your project folder name]/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now you can access like

http://example.com/controller/method

May it's helpfull for you

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the heck you're doing with all that code, but I just put this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And boom.

Comment: This solution is not working for me either. Pretty much the same as the 4th block I tried. Don't know how this can work without RewriteEngine on or anything.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to vote down a comment because it doesn't work with your overly-elaborate setup. Install a blank CI and try it - you'll find it works.

Comment: I did not vote down your answer, someone else did :/