# How should I minimize url in CodeIgniter 2.2.3

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and I love to use it in my future projects too.
I having a big time problem to make my url user friendly.
I have a website running that has a lot of pages, so URLs get too big and they look too bad.
So what I want to do, is shorten my URLs. For example:

```
www.abc.com/index.php/main/home
```

I want to make something like this:

```
www.abc.com/home
```

So my question is, How should I do this thing in `CodeIgniter 2.2.3` ? Is there any demo?
I was see so many links for it but it can not full fill my requirement so please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556522/codeigniter-remove-index-php-from-url/28644165#28644165

Answer (score 0):

You can use `routes` for this purpose

To remove `index.php` use `.htaccess` with following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in `config.php`

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

now in your routes `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['home']='main/home';
```

Comment: thanks buddy..the problem is in my C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf /httpd config file.. so i un commment rewrite mode so its fine and now working great..thanks again for ur valuable time and suggest..

Answer (score 0):

To remove `index.php`, place `.htaccess` outside application folder (root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

To short URL, use `config/routes.php`

```
$route['home'] = "main/home";
```

> Ex:
>   To use this `<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>main">I'm Moving</a>`

Comment: thanks buddy..the problem is in my C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf /httpd config file.. so i un commment rewrite mode so its fine and now working great..thanks again for ur valuable time and suggest..

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly i create .htaccess file and put this code in it..

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /xyz.co/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

than go to application/config/routes.php and put below code.

$default_controller = "auth";
$controller_exceptions = array('main');
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';
$route['404_override'] = 'error';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

and in config.php

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

thats all...
```